# Is there any possibility to load the Ubuntu Touch image at your destop instead of the uTouch dual boot app?

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch

I just wondered if I can download the Ubuntu Touch image at my destop instead of at the phone. Would be much faster in my case.

Thanks for every answer